# Numerical methods to minimize a maximum

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Let $r(t)$ be the function:
$r(t) = \sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}$, where
$x(t) = 3b (1 − t)^2 t + 3c (1 − t) t^2 + a t^3$, and
$y(t) = a (1 − t)^3 + 3c (1 − t)^2 t + 3b (1 − t) t^2$

Now define $f$:
$f(a, b, c) = \max( |r(t) - 1|, 0 \leq t \leq 1)$

Based on the plots I've made, $f$ should have a local minimum near:
$(a, b, c) = (1.0, 0.5, 1.0)$

But I'm struggling to find a way to numerically calculate it.

Ideally, I'd like to solve this using Wolfram Alpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Or Maxima:
https://maxima.sourceforge.io/download.html

But I'd be grateful if you know of any way to do it!

I've spent almost a full day on this. Everything I've tried is either interpreted incorrectly, or eventually fails due to a timeout.

Comment: This would not be an easy problem since $r^2(t)$ is a polynomial of degree 6

Comment: That's right, it really isn't. I have an analytical solution to a simpler version of it--which is useful--but not as useful as this solution would be...

Comment: Is there any other way to tackle it? Perhaps if I could generate a plot, maybe I could zoom in on the maxima visually until the desired level of precision has been reached? Or maybe there's another way to look at the problem? If $|r(t) - 1|$ were replaced by $(r(t) - 1)^2$, that would work just as well when finding the minimum.

Comment: @Spencer Do you mean to estimate the global minimum numerically?

Comment: That's an important clarification. I'm just looking to estimate the local minimum near (1.0, 0.5, 1.0). (Knowing the global minimum would be even better, though!)

Comment: @Spencer So you want to find any one local minimizer near $(1,1/2, 1)$ with numerical values 9-12 significant digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern PCs are so incredibly fast that a simple problem like this readily lends itself to a modified Monte Carlo approach. The idea is to generate many random triples $(a, b, c)$ in the vicinity of the approximate solution until one finds a parameter triple that reduces the maximum error to a new minimum, then search from the new temporary optimum, *reducing the search radius slightly* with each new solution found. Likewise, the search for the maximum of $|r(t)-1|$ is based on using many random arguments uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$.

Using this approach, and setting the initial search radii equal to the initial parameter values (that is, $a=1\pm1, b=0.5\pm0.5, c=1\pm1$), I found the following solution in about two minutes using the ISO-C99 program shown below: $a=1.00005519, b=0.55342686, c=0.99873585$. An exhaustive test with all arguments $t$ representable as single-precision operands shows that $\max(|r(t)-1|, 0 \le t\le1)$ with these parameter is $0.00005579$.

While this approach may lack elegance, relying instead in brute-force manner on the computational throughput of modern computing platforms, it has frequently served me well in tackling small problems such as the one presented in the question.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXSTEP   (0x7fffffff) // 2**31-1
#define SHRINKAGE (0.9f)       // heuristic
#define FUNC_EVAL (10000000)

float pow2 (float x)
{
    return x * x;
}

float pow3 (float x)
{
    return x * x * x;
}

float x (float t, float a, float b, float c)
{
    return 3 * b * pow2 (1 - t) * t + 3 * c * (1 - t) * pow2 (t) + a * pow3 (t);
}

float y (float t, float a, float b, float c)
{
    return a * pow3 (1-t) + 3 * c * pow2 (1 - t) * t + 3 * b * (1-t) * pow2 (t);
}

float r (float t, float a, float b, float c)
{
    return hypotf (x (t, a, b, c), y (t, a, b, c));
}


// George Marsaglia's KISS PRNG, period 2**123. Newsgroup sci.math, 21 Jan 1999
// Bug fix: Greg Rose, "KISS: A Bit Too Simple" http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static uint32_t kiss_z=362436069, kiss_w=521288629;
static uint32_t kiss_jsr=123456789, kiss_jcong=380116160;
#define znew (kiss_z=36969*(kiss_z&65535)+(kiss_z>>16))
#define wnew (kiss_w=18000*(kiss_w&65535)+(kiss_w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew )
#define SHR3 (kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<13),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr>>17), \
              kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<5))
#define CONG (kiss_jcong=69069*kiss_jcong+1234567)
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

int main (void)
{
    float a, b, c, t, f, max_f, min_max_f;
    int step = 0;

    float best_a = 1.0f;
    float best_b = 0.5f;
    float best_c = 1.0f;
    float scal = 1.0f;
    min_max_f = INFINITY;
    do {
        a = best_a + scal * (KISS * 0x1.0p-31 - 1.0f); 
        b = best_b + scal * (KISS * 0x1.0p-32 - 0.5f);
        c = best_c + scal * (KISS * 0x1.0p-31 - 1.0f);
        max_f = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < FUNC_EVAL; i++) {
            t = KISS * 0x1.0p-32; // in [0, 1]
            f = fabsf (r (t, a, b, c) - 1);
            if (f > max_f) max_f = f;
            if (max_f > min_max_f) break; 
        }
        if (max_f < min_max_f) {
            best_a = a;
            best_b = b;  
            best_c = c;  
            scal = scal * SHRINKAGE;
            min_max_f = max_f;
            printf ("min_max_f=%.8f a=%.8f b=%.8f c=%.8f [scal=%.8f step=%d]\n",
                    min_max_f, a, b, c, scal, step);
        }
        step++;
    } while (step < MAXSTEP);
    printf ("exhaustive test (a=%.8f b=%.8f c=%.8f)\n", best_a, best_b, best_c);
    t = 0.0f;
    max_f = 0.0f;
    do {
        f = fabsf (r (t, best_a, best_b, best_c) - 1);
        if (f > max_f) max_f = f;
        t = nextafterf (t, INFINITY);
    } while (t <= 1.0f);
    printf ("max_f=%.8f\n", max_f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```
````

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: No need for Monte Carlo in this case... Hooke & Jeeves (search along coordinate directions + step adjustment) gets to thge minimumn in a fraction of the time.

Comment: @PierreCarre There is ample room for yet another answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

7/22/2022 Update:

I rewrote this algorithm to achieve more significant figures without further alteration.  However, it likely takes at least several minutes on a typical computer, and I wouldn't claim that it achieves all 9-12 significant figures sought (4-5 is a much more reasonable claim).  I wasn't aware of the number of significant figures sought when I first wrote an answer.  The algorithm gives values of a = 1.000052922, b = 0.553420099, and c = 0.998742294.

I appreciate the comments regarding my approach to this problem.

I did attempt to write a "Hooke & Jeeves-like" algorithm in R based on feedback from @PierreCarre and a general description of the algorithm found online.  I found that even modest changes in the value of a,b, and c can alter the shape of $|r(t) - 1|$ across the interval for $t$, implying that the maximum and corresponding minimums also change.  When I tried varying the coefficients one at a time, the minimum of $f$ did not always decrease.  Another challenge is that typical optimization routines for Nelder-Meade and similar algorithms in R most commonly minimize a function based on the independent variable rather than the coefficients, which makes their use less obvious for problems like this.

Regarding the comment of @Spencer, the algorithm can only find a,b, and c that yield the lowest value of $f$ in the search space.  Outside of that, I wouldn't claim to provide any guarantees of achieving a local minimum because the shape of $f$ can vary so much based on the values of a,b, and c.

With the previously mentioned caveats regarding the runtime and the limited number of significant figures, I will leave this algorithm online in case someone finds it useful.

```
#Written in R 4.2.1
require(data.table)
##define functions
x = function(t,a = aa,b = bb,c = cc) 3*b*(1-t)^2*t + 3*c*(1-t)*t^2 + a*t^3
y = function(t,a = aa,b = bb,c = cc) a*(1-t)^3 + 3*c*(1-t)^2*t + 3*b*(1-t)*t^2
rt = function(t,a,b,c) sqrt(x(t,a,b,c)^2 + y(t,a,b,c)^2)
f = function(t,a,b,c) max(abs(rt(t,a,b,c) - 1))
 
avec = NULL;bvec = NULL; cvec = NULL
granvec = c(1e-2,1e-3,1e-4,1e-5,1e-6,1e-7,1e-8,1e-9)
fansvec = NULL
a = 1;b = .55;c = 1
sn = 20  ##number to define a,b,c sequences
 
for(j in 1:length(granvec)){
gran = granvec[j]   #granularity of the search space
aa = seq(a - sn*gran,a + sn*gran,gran)
bb = seq(b - sn*gran,b + sn*gran,gran)
cc = seq(c - sn*gran,c + sn*gran,gran)
tt = seq(0,1,1e-4)
#data frame of all combinations in search space to specified granularity
sspace2 = CJ(aa,bb,cc)

ansframe2 = NULL
for(i in 1:dim(sspace2)[1]){
ansframe2[i] = f(tt, a = sspace2$aa[i], b = sspace2$bb[i], c = sspace2$cc[i])
}

sspace2$fans = ansframe2
sspace2[sspace2$fans == min(sspace2$fans),]

fansvec[j] = sspace2[sspace2$fans == min(sspace2$fans),]$fans[1]
 
if(j > 1){
if(fansvec[j] > fansvec[j-1]){
print("Algorithm is not converging to the true local minimum")
}}
a = sspace2[sspace2$fans == min(sspace2$fans),]$aa[1]
b = sspace2[sspace2$fans == min(sspace2$fans),]$bb[1]
c = sspace2[sspace2$fans == min(sspace2$fans),]$cc[1]
avec[j] = a;bvec[j] = b;cvec[j] = c
}

ansvec = data.frame(avec,bvec,cvec)
options(digits = 15)
f(tt,a = a,b = b,c = c)
[1] 5.55341550056987e-05
a
[1] 1.000052922
b
[1] 0.553420099
c
[1] 0.998742294
```

Comment: This might work... I'm looking for numerical values with 9-12 significant digits, but perhaps the granularity could gradually increase as the search area shrinks? I wonder how you would know if you've failed to find a local minimum because the granularity was too high?

It might be possible to outsource some of the computation. Maxima can efficiently calculate $f(a, b, c)$, although I haven't found a way to get Maxima to find the minimum $f$ over a range of parameters.

Comment: And thank you, too.

Comment: Although this may work for a (very) small number of space dimensions, brute force approach is rarely the way to go. Even very simple (and as easy to implement as this) local search methods like Hooke & Jeeves or Nelder & Mead can do this in a fraction of the time. And this is without using derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts**:

Since $r(t) = r(1 - t)$ for all $t\in [0, 1]$, we consider the following equivalent problem:
$$\min_{a, b, c} ~ \max_{t\in [0, 1/2]} ~ [r(t) - 1]^2. $$

With $t \in [0, 1/2]$, let $s = (1/2 - t)^2 \in [0, 1/4]$ (correspondingly $t = 1/2 - \sqrt s$).
The optimization problem becomes
$$\min_{a, b, c} ~ \max_{s \in [0, 1/4]} ~ (\sqrt{As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D} - 1)^2$$
where
\begin{align*}
 A &= 2(a + 3b - 3c)^2, \\
 B &= \frac{15a^2 - 6ab - 30ac - 9b^2 + 54bc - 9c^2}{2}, \\
 C &= \frac{15a^2 - 6ab + 30ac - 9b^2 - 54bc - 9c^2}{8}, \\
 D &= \frac{(a + 3b + 3c)^2}{32}.
\end{align*}

Let $$g(s) := (\sqrt{As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D} - 1)^2.$$
We have $g(0) = [(a + 3b + 3c)\sqrt 2/8 - 1]^2$ and $g(1/4) = (|a| - 1)^2$.

We have
$$g'(s) = 2(\sqrt{As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D} - 1)\cdot \frac{3As^2 + 2Bs + C}{2\sqrt{As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D}}.$$
(*Note*: At maximum, $\sqrt{As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D} - 1 \ne 0$. So, we only need to consider $3As^2 + 2Bs + C = 0$.)

So we can solve $\max_{s \in [0, 1/4]} ~ (\sqrt{As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D} - 1)^2$ in closed form.

Moreover, based on the existing answer, I believe in the neighborhood of $a = 1.000052922, b = 0.553420099, c = 0.998742294$, the global maximizer $s^\ast$ is one of the roots of $3As^2 + 2Bs + C = 0$.